# java generics and extends

Tags: java

I've read the docs but don't see what I'm doing wrong here ...
the goal is a generic collection class Wlist to contain ItemIFs.
The Java source for java.util.TreeMap uses:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
  Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
  cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
```

I was hoping to avoid the cast by using the code below, but
get a warning "unchecked call" when I compile with -Xlint:unchecked.
Suggestions?

```
interface ItemIF<TP> {
  int compareItem( TP vv);
} // end interface ItemIF


class Wlist<TP extends ItemIF> {
TP coreItem;
void insert( TP item) {
  // *** Following line gets: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call   ***
  // *** to compareItem(TP) as a member of the raw type ItemIF      ***
  int icomp = coreItem.compareItem( item);
}
} // end class


class Item implements ItemIF<Item> {
String stg;
public Item( String stg) {
  this.stg = stg;
}
public int compareItem( Item vv) {
  return stg.compareTo( vv.stg);
}
} // end class Item


class Testit {
public static void main( String[] args) {
  Wlist<Item> bt = new Wlist<Item>();
  bt.insert( new Item("alpha"));
}
} // end class Testit
```

Comment: (Note `TreeMap` uses the same class whether being used with a `Comparator` or assuming the type is `Comparable`. This is a bad idea, and leads to the necessarily dirty implementation.)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
class Wlist<TP extends ItemIF<TP>>
```

otherwise you are using `ItemIF` as a raw type giving you the raw type warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareItem( Item vv)
```

Uses `Item` not `ItemIF` so you are downcasting when you call it with `TP extends ItemIF`.

Try changing it to

```
public int compareItem( ItemIF vv)
```

Comment: This does not work because when using "ItemIF vv",  vv is no longer of type Item and so does not have access to stg.  So we must use a  cast to access vv.stg.  This is what java.util.TreeMap does and what I'm trying to avoid.